# Can't deploy RoR app to Heroku - SQLite3 already removed from Gem.file and Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku but am getting the following error every time I push the master branch.

```
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_d18bbff5ffdeba017c7010c0d8b12d5f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_d18bbff5ffdeba017c7010c0d8b12d5f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_d18bbff5ffdeba017c7010c0d8b12d5f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:        sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

SQLite3 has been removed from my gem and gem lock files and it has all been pushed to git and merged with the master branch. My database.yml has been updated to use postgresql instead of sqlite3. Any ideas what is causing this to fail?

The referenced files are listed here:

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#############################################################
# Non-Default Gems Added To Project

gem 'clearance'

# Postgresql version downgraded to be compatible with ActiveRecord
gem 'pg', '~>0.18.0'

gem 'activerecord'

gem 'figaro'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'heroku'

#############################################################
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5)
      actionview (= 4.2.5)
      activejob (= 4.2.5)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.5)
      actionview (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.5)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.5)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.0)
    clearance (1.16.1)
      bcrypt
      email_validator (~> 1.4)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    email_validator (1.6.0)
      activemodel
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (0.12.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.21)
    figaro (1.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    hashie (3.5.7)
    i18n (0.9.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.6)
    jwt (1.5.6)
    loofah (2.2.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    oauth2 (1.4.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.13)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.8.1)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6, < 3.6.0)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.5.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.1)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    pg (0.18.4)
    rack (1.6.8)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.5)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5)
      actionview (= 4.2.5)
      activejob (= 4.2.5)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.5)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rdoc (4.3.0)
    sass (3.5.5)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.6)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord
  byebug
  clearance
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  figaro
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  omniauth-facebook
  pg (~> 0.18.0)
  rails (= 4.2.5)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

**Database.yml**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") {5} %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  <<: *default
  database: airbnb_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: airbnb_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: airbnb_production
  username: (removed)
  password: (removed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue- even though I was pushing my changes to Git, I had not pulled the master back to my computer. The file being sent when I ran `git push heroku master` still included the **sqlite3 gem** even though it was deleted out in my file and on the Github master. Once I ran `git checkout master` and `git pull origin master`, I was able to deploy to Heroku.